# Docker Container - touch: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker

I have a strange issue here, where I don't see the point what it is going wrong.

I am running everything in a docker container on my Linux box (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

```
docker run -ti --rm promregator/promregator:0.2.1 /bin/bash
```

(note: the image is available publicly via `hub.docker.com`). The command

```
docker version
```

(on the host) returns

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

In the container, I want to create a file like this:

```
promregator@6a68713fafc9:/$ cd /opt/promregator
promregator@6a68713fafc9:/opt/promregator$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
```

(promregator is the user, with which the image runs as default). Note that

- The directory is coming directly from the image and is not volume-mapped.
- The directory is owned by the very same user and the permissions are 0750:

  ```
  promregator@6a68713fafc9:/opt/promregator$ ls -al
  total 34348
  drwxr-x--- 2 promregator promregator     4096 Apr  1 01:00 .
  drwxr-xr-x 5 root        root            4096 Mar 20 01:01 ..
  -rw-r----- 1 promregator promregator 35159385 Apr  1 00:59 promregator.jar
  -rwxrwx--- 1 promregator promregator      642 Apr  1 00:57 promregator.sh
  ```

  Numerically, the user is 1000

  ```
  promregator@6a68713fafc9:/opt/promregator$ ls -aln .
  total 34348
  drwxr-x--- 2 1000 1000     4096 Apr  1 01:00 .
  [...]
  ```

Note also, that the very same operation works on `/home/promregator`:

```
promregator@6a68713fafc9:/opt/promregator$ cd /home/promregator
promregator@6a68713fafc9:~$ touch test
promregator@6a68713fafc9:~$ ls -al .
total 8
drwx------ 2 promregator promregator 4096 Apr  7 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root        root        4096 Apr  7 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 promregator promregator    0 Apr  7 11:45 test
promregator@6a68713fafc9:~$ ls -aln .
total 8
drwx------ 2 1000 1000 4096 Apr  7 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3    0    0 4096 Apr  7 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    0 Apr  7 11:45 test
```

Note that, if I run the container as root by using

```
docker run -ti --rm -u root promregator/promregator:0.2.1 /bin/bash
```

I am able to create the file in the first location:

```
root@eb29fa8acb95:/# cd /opt/promregator/
root@eb29fa8acb95:/opt/promregator# touch test
```

This tells me that there is something "strange" with the user `promregator`.

On a different host (I have compared the sha1 ids of the images), the file can be created as expected, if the container was started with `docker run -ti --rm promregator/promregator:0.2.1 /bin/bash`. The version information of that host indicates

```
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:11:19 2017
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:09:54 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Any ideas, hints, ... for me, what this could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. My solution is to turn off selinux by "setenforce 0".

Comment: You have a source for that?

Comment: Where did you do this? On the docker host or during building the mage?